# Will TensorFlow XLA deal with sparse tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I've read the XLA prerelease document here.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/resources/xla_prerelease#xla_accelerated_linear_algebra

It discusses datatypes of elements, but does not go into much detail about the data organization of the tensors themselves.  How will operations on SparseTensor objects be handled once XLA is available?

Comment: Sounds like a comment more appropriate for their GitHub issues or IRC or something. Maybe you would have more luck there?

Comment: Code and more documentation will be released later in Jan 2017

Answer (score 1):

The layouts restrict the data organization of input and output tensors and don't include sparse layouts, although as Jingyue suggests, they could be extended in the future. The internal representation of tensors in the AST can in principle be anything a backend wants, and it is expected that the compiler may reorganize the data to different layouts for the convenience of different operators implemented by different backends.

I am not aware that anyone has put much thought into how to do this efficiently for sparse tensors. In principle maybe it could be done as a compiler pass to infer sparsity and propagate it, with sparse implementations for all the relevant operators. Nothing like that exists today.

Answer (score 0):

No, XLA focuses on dense tensors and doesn't deal with sparse tensors in an efficient way **today**.

It could be easily extended to allow users to express some sparsity using [layouts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/resources/xla_prerelease#layout) (e.g. interior padding).

Answer (score 0):

Sparse data is something we'd like to have working, though it has some challenges. E.g. currently XLA depends on knowing the exact size of every buffer statically. We could certainly find a way to deal with that, but have been focusing on dense data so far.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later, XLA seems to have some support for sparse tensors, and working well at that. My workflow involves sparse tensors for very high dimensional data that would be prohibitive to keep in memory, then slicing and manipulating and finally performing math ops on a lower dimensional sense tensor. For slicing sparse tensors I’m getting a roughly 4x speed up with xla